# Is there a way to add additional files to file upload before submitting to server ?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

using a simple input control:

```
<input type="file" id="demo" multiple />
<input type="submit value="Submit Final" />
```

is there a way to customize using JavaScript/Jquery to allow for adding additional files on a second and third 'browse' button click ? (before clicking button 'Submit Final'). On the server side I am using Microsoft MVC.

Thank you.

I've already tried some jquery plugins, but could not find suitable one.

don't want to submit to server until the 'Submit Final' button is clicked.

Comment: can you elaborate on the use case and how a user would use this? what if they add the wrong file to the list of uploads by accident? if there is only 1 control that always appends files to a list of files to be uploaded then they wouldn't be able to clear that list without reloading the page... or maybe I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: that's a good point. I figured out a solution and will post it.

Answer (score 0):

figured out a solution:

```
<input type="file" class="files" id="files" name="files" multiple onchange="javascript:updateList()">

<div id="selectedFiles" style="margin-left:10px"></div>


<script>
updateList = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('files');
    var output = document.getElementById('selectedFiles');

    var f = $("#selectedFiles").data("files");

    if (f != null) {


        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            f.push(input.files.item(i));

        }

        $("#selectedFiles").data("files", f);

    }
    else {
        var dFiles = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            dFiles.push(input.files.item(i));
        }

            $("#selectedFiles").data("files", dFiles);

    }


    var f = $("#selectedFiles").data("files");
    output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < f.length; ++i) {

        if (validateFileExt(f[i].name))
            output.innerHTML += '<li>' + f[i].name + ' (' + f[i].size + ')' + '<a onclick="removeFile(this)" href="javascript:void(0);">&nbsp;remove</a>' + '</li>';
    }
    output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up any front end display that shows the image(s) before the user submits the form. I've added some bootstrap4 display classes that work well for this use case. The jquery handles the file select dialogue, instead of the submit button.

```
$('[file-upload]').change(function () {
    var File = this.files;

    if (File && File[0]) {
        ReadImage(File[0]);
    }
});
});

var ReadImage = function (file) {
var s = document.getElementById('UpdatedActionsFileUpload');
s.value = 'ReverseDelete';
var reader = new FileReader;
var image = new Image;
image.addEventListener('error', imagenotfound);
var imagenotfound = function () {
    alert("imagenotfound");
};

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function (_file) {
    image.src = _file.target.result;
    image.onload = function () {
        $('[target-img]').attr('src', _file.target.result);

        $('[img-preview]').show();
    }
};
};
var ClearPreview = function () {
$('[file-upload]').val('');
$('[img-description]').text('');
$('#img-preview').css({ "visibility": "visible" });
$('[img-preview]').hide();
var s = document.getElementById('UpdatedActionsFileUpload');
s.value = 'Delete';
};
```

And then some html

```
<div img-preview class="thumbnail" style="display:none">
            <img class="img-fluid" target-img />
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="#in-form" onclick="ClearPreview()"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> </a>
                <p img-description></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```